# Converting String Related Function from C++ to C

Tags: c++, c

there is a function which I have written it myself for large numbers' Add (+) operator in C++, now I'm trying to convert it to C language but there is some problems with strings :( I tried so many things but it seems it is not working, Here is a piece of my code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

string num1,num2,Result;

string AddF (string num1, string num2)
{
    string Result;
    char d;
    int sum,f=0,Len1=num1.length(),Len2=num2.length();
    while(Len1>=0 || Len2>=0)
    {
        sum=0;Len1--;Len2--;
        if (Len1>=0)
            sum+=num1[Len1]-'0';
        if (Len2>=0)
            sum+=num2[Len2]-'0';
        d=((sum+f)%10)+'0';
        Result=d+string(Result);
        f=(sum+f)/10;
    }
    d=f+'0';
    if (f!=0)
        Result=d+string(Result);
    if(Result[0]=='0')
        Result.erase(0,1);
    return Result;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Please Enter 1th Number: "; cin >> num1;
    cout << "Please Enter 2th Number: "; cin >> num2;
    Result=AddF(num1,num2);
}
```

Now My Converted Code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *num1,*num2,*Result;

char* AddF (char *num1, char *num2)
{
    char *Result,*d;
    int sum,f=0,Len1=strlen(num1),Len2=strlen(num2),Temp;
    while(Len1>=0 || Len2>=0)
    {
        sum=0;Len1--;Len2--;
        if (Len1>=0)
            sum+=num1[Len1]-'0';
        if (Len2>=0)
            sum+=num2[Len2]-'0';
        Temp=((sum+f)%10);
        itoa(Temp,d,10);
        strcat(d,Result);
        Result=d;
        f=(sum+f)/10;
    }
    itoa(f,d,10);
    if (f!=0)
    {
        strcat(d,Result);
        Result=d;
    }
    if(Result[0]=='0')
        memmove(&Result[0], &Result[0 + 1], strlen(Result) - 0);
    return Result;
}

int main()
{
    printf ("Please Enter 1th Number: "); scanf ("%s",&num1);
    printf ("Please Enter 2th Number: "); scanf ("%s",&num2);
    Result=AddF(num1,num2);
}
```

It will Crash when It reach last line.

Comment: You need allocate memory for `Result` and `d`and other pointers. Use `malloc`

Comment: Just a side note: `1th` and `2th`? I believe those are `1st` and `2nd` but hell, what do I know...

Comment: but I need to use dynamic strings, maybe user enter a 1000 digits numbers or maybe 10 digits one, who knows? does any one know any source code for large numbers calculation in C which supports * / + -?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because of several reasongs

1. You have to allocate `d`. I would recomend you declare `d` as an array and use the `snptrinf` or `_snprintf` functions something like

   ```
   char d[32];
   int  x = 3;

   snprintf(d, sizeof(d), "%d", x);
   ```
2. You have to pass an allocated memory buffer to `scanf` too, you can pass an array, something like

   ```
   char num1[32];
   char num2[32];

   scanf("%31s", num1);
   scanf("%31s", num2);
   ```

   and the same goes for `Result`
3. You are returning an array instead of a pointer from the `AddF()` function, you can use a temporary array and then copy the string at the end, and return the copy, **don't solve the problem using global variables**.
4. You are assigning to `Result` unecessarily, if you use `strcat()` the destination string will be always appendend to the end of the source string.

   And this will in fact be a mistake, since you declared `Result` as a pointer, and you are making point somewhere else, thus loosing the reference to the original pointer.

This might be what you want

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *AddF (char *number0, char *number1)
{
    char *result;
    int   sum;
    int   carry;
    int   lengths[2];
    int   count;

    if ((number0 == NULL) || (number1 == NULL))
        return NULL;

    lengths[0] = strlen(number0);
    lengths[1] = strlen(number1);

    result = malloc(lengths[0] + lengths[1] + 1);
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;

    carry = 0;
    count = 0;
    while (lengths[0] >= 0 || lengths[1] >= 0)
    {
        lengths[0]--;
        lengths[1]--;

        sum = 0;
        if (lengths[0] >= 0)
            sum += number0[lengths[0]] - '0';
        if (lengths[1] >= 0)
            sum += number1[lengths[1]] - '0';
        memmove(result + 1, result, ++count);

        result[0] = ((sum + carry) % 10) + '0';
        carry     = (sum + carry) / 10;
    }
    result[count] = '\0';

    if (result[0] == '0')
        memmove(result, result + 1, count);

    if (carry == 0)
        return result;
    memmove(result + 1, result, ++count);

    result[0]     = carry + '0';
    result[count] = '\0';

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char  *numbers[2] = {NULL, NULL};
    char  *result;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0 ; i < sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(*numbers) ; i++)
    {
        char   chr;
        size_t length;

        length = 0;

        printf ("Please Enter %ldth Number: ", 1 + i);
        while ((chr = getchar()) != '\n')
        {
            char *number;

            number = realloc(numbers[i], (2 + length));
            if (number == NULL)
            {
                if (numbers[0] != NULL)
                    free(numbers[0]);
                if (numbers[1] != NULL)
                    free(numbers[1]);
                return -1;
            }
            number[length] = chr;
            numbers[i]     = number;
            length        += 1;
        }
        numbers[i][length] = '\0';
    }

    result = AddF(numbers[0], numbers[1]);

    if (result != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", result);
        free(result);
    }

    if (numbers[0] != NULL)
        free(numbers[0]);
    if (numbers[1] != NULL)
        free(numbers[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Um, it is missing a lot more than allocating memory for `d` (`num1` and `num2`, for example).

Comment: but I need to use dynamic strings, maybe user enter a 1000 digits numbers or maybe 10 digits one, who knows?

Comment: There is no such thing as dynamic strings in c you will need to handle user input in a different way then. And use **dynamic memory allocation**

Comment: @Stranger I updated the code to use dynamic allocation, check it.

Comment: @Stranger if `snprintf` gives a compilation error, just change it to `_snprintf`

Comment: As far as I can see, the result is backwards and the last carry isn't considered.

Comment: @MOehm true, but what you mean the last carry isn't considered, my english doesn't interpret that.

Comment: When the result has one digit more than the input numbers, e.g. 555 + 555 == 1110, the leading 1 isn't written. (I think the overflowing parts of the digit sums are called carry, because they are carried over to the next digit.)

Comment: @MOehm I didn't even see what the program was actually doing, this version is a lot better, and indeed, the term carry makes a lot of sense, so much that I changed the identifier name.

Comment: @iharob thank you very much, I have 3 other functions (* / -) which needs conversion but I can not understand your codes as much as a pro C Programmer. It is a little complex for me, Can you give me a hand converting them please?

Comment: @Stranger this is my e-mail iharob@gmail.com, Oh, if the answer works for you, you can accept it by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Oh yes, Just forgot :D

Comment: @iharob I have sent you an E-Mail :)